# Syntax error sql and save values in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I try to create a query with pdo. I want that only the rows are saved in the array $result, that have the value between `$lo` and `$loo` or/ and `$la` and `$laa`. I´m very new in pdo sorry about the difficult question.

Error Message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<= 0 or latitude >= 0 and <= 0) ORDER BY date' at line 1

```
    $range = 'range';
  $_COOKIE["$range"];

$longitude = 'longitude';
$_COOKIE["$longitude"];
$latitude = 'latitude';
$_COOKIE["$latitude"];


$onemile = 0,005581257;
$le = $range * $onemile; 
$lo = $longitude + $le;
$loo = $longitude - $le;
$la = $latitude + $le;
$laa = $latitude - $le;


$hostname='localhost';
        $user='root';
        $password='';



                try {
                        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=log",$user,$password);

                        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                         $sql = "SELECT id, autorid, date, longitude, latitude, title, text FROM post WHERE  (longitude >= $loo and <= $lo or latitude >= $laa and <= $la) ORDER BY date";
  if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {

     $result = $res->fetchAll();
     print_r($result);
   }


                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't chain comparisons like that. Each where statement must include the identifier you are doing a comparison on.

You also need to use parenthesis to enforce operator precedence (that was going to be your next error).

```
SELECT id, autorid, date, longitude, latitude, title, text 
FROM post 
WHERE  (
    longitude >= $loo and longitude <= $lo
) 
OR (
    latitude >= $laa and latitude <= $la
) 
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Syntax must be like:

`WHERE  (longitude between $loo and $lo or latitude  between $laa and $la)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` conditions are missing some values:

```
longitude >= $loo and <= $lo or latitude >= $laa and <= $la
```

These are the actual conditions you're using:

```
longitude >= $loo
<= $lo
latitude >= $laa
<= $la
```

Notice how two of them aren't actually comparing anything.  Maybe you meant this:

```
longitude >= $loo and longitude <= $lo or latitude >= $laa and latitude <= $la
```

You might also want to nest some parentheses to make conditions more explicit:

```
(longitude >= $loo and longitude <= $lo) or (latitude >= $laa and latitude <= $la)
```